# Get a list of items sent between two dates pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, merge

I am new to python and i'm not sure how to achive what i'm trying to do. I have two pandas dataframes and I need to combine them. One dataframe is called `'cust'` and the other one is called `'items'`, Below is the code to create both the datasets:

```
import pandas as pd
  
cust = {'id': [212175, 286170, 361739, 297438, 415712],
        'date_start': ['20/05/2022', '18/05/2022', '10/08/2021', '20/01/2022', '30/07/2021']}

items = {'id': [212175, 212175, 212175, 212175, 212175, 286170, 286170, 286170, 286170, 286170],
        'item': ['PX002','PY005','PX003','PX003','NX002','PX002','PY005','PX003','PX003','NX002'], 
        'date_sent': ['21/05/2022','10/05/2022','01/06/2022','01/07/2021','15/08/2022','19/05/2022','10/07/2022','15/07/2022','10/04/2022','15/06/2022']}

# Create DataFrame
cust_df = pd.DataFrame(cust)
items_df = pd.DataFrame(items)
```

Cust_df:

```
id     date_start
212175  20/05/2022
286170  18/05/2022
361739  10/08/2021
297438  20/01/2022
415712  30/07/2021
```

items_df:

```
 id      item    date_sent
212175  PX002   21/05/2022
212175  PY005   10/05/2022
212175  PX003   01/06/2022
212175  PX003   01/07/2021
212175  NX002   15/08/2022
286170  PX002   19/05/2022
286170  PY005   10/07/2022
286170  PX003   15/07/2022
286170  PX003   10/04/2022
286170  NX002   15/06/2022
```

I need to find out all the items that were sent to every customer between two dates. The start date for each customer is different and should be taken from the date_start field present in the cust_df data frame. The end date for every customer is the same which is `'12/08/2022'`. So, the date range for customer `212175` will be  `20/05/2022 - 12/08/2022`, and i need to find out all the items sent to this customer between these dates. My desired output dataframe should look like the below:

Output_dataframe:

```
id       item   date_sent   date_start
212175  PX002   21/05/2022  20/05/2022
212175  PX003   01/06/2022  20/05/2022
286170  PX002   19/05/2022  18/05/2022
286170  PY005   10/07/2022  18/05/2022
286170  PX003   15/07/2022  18/05/2022
286170  NX002   15/06/2022  18/05/2022
```

In the output table we can see that for `ID = 212175`, only 3 items are showing. That's because only 3 items were sent during the window `20/05/2022 - 12/08/2022`.

For `ID = 286170`, only 1 item `'PX003'` isn't showing in the desired output and that's because the date this item was sent was on `'10/04/2022'`, which is before the `date_start (18/05/2022)` for customer `286170`.

Any help appreciated. Thanks

Comment: this is a simple inner merge ```pd.merge(items_df, cust_df, how='inner', on='id')
```

Comment: An inner merge will merge together all the values from both datasets where there is a match on id. However, I don't want all the items in the merged data set and instead only want the items that were sent between certain dates.

Comment: one can always filter after merging using [datetime datatypes](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html)

Comment: I was a little confused why `212175  PX005   10/05/2022  20/05/2022` is in the output, as May 10 is before the start date (May 20) ..

Comment: My bad, that shouldn't have been there in the output. I've changed it in case someone comes across it in future and it doesn't confuses them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, use a [`merge_asof`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html):

```
cust_df['date_start'] = pd.to_datetime(cust_df['date_start'], dayfirst=True)
items_df['date_sent'] = pd.to_datetime(items_df['date_sent'], dayfirst=True)

out = (pd
   .merge_asof(items_df.sort_values(by='date_sent'),
               cust_df.sort_values(by='date_start'),
               by='id', left_on='date_sent', right_on='date_start')
   .dropna(subset='date_start')
   .loc[lambda d: d['date_sent'] < pd.Timestamp("2022-08-12")]
   .sort_values(by=['id', 'item']) # optional
)
```

output:

```
       id   item  date_sent date_start
9  212175  NX002 2022-08-15 2022-05-20
4  212175  PX002 2022-05-21 2022-05-20
5  212175  PX003 2022-06-01 2022-05-20
6  286170  NX002 2022-06-15 2022-05-18
3  286170  PX002 2022-05-19 2022-05-18
8  286170  PX003 2022-07-15 2022-05-18
7  286170  PY005 2022-07-10 2022-05-18
```

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what i'm after but for some reason I wasn't able to run the code.           
                                                                                                                                                   I got this error: TypeError: Index(...) must be called with a collection of some kind, 'date_start' was passed

Comment: Can you comment all lines an uncomment one by one to identify the one giving you the error. Which pandas version are you using? Try to update.

Comment: It's the
.dropna(subset='date_start') , line thats causing the error. If i take this line out then the code runs fine. and my resulting data frame is:


9 212175 NX002 2022-08-15 2022-05-20
4 212175 PX002 2022-05-21 2022-05-20
0 212175 PX003 2021-07-01 NaT
5 212175 PX003 2022-06-01 2022-05-20
2 212175 PY005 2022-05-10 NaT
6 286170 NX002 2022-06-15 2022-05-18
3 286170 PX002 2022-05-19 2022-05-18
1 286170 PX003 2022-04-10 NaT
8 286170 PX003 2022-07-15 2022-05-18
7 286170 PY005 2022-07-10 2022-05-18

Comment: I can filter out separately the rows with NAT in the date_start field to be fair :), so it does solve my problem. Thanks

Comment: I think it's due to the pandas version, the way `dropna` works has changed over time, I can't tell you the exact workaround (best would be to use the latest version!)

Comment: Just a minor note, I think `pd.Timestamp("12/08/2022")` evaluates to December 8th, whereas the intended solution was for August 12th..

Comment: @dermen thanks, I admit I just copy pasted ;) Always using the unambiguous `'YYYY-MM-DD'` format otherwise!

Answer (score 1):

Merge and filter

```
m = pd.merge(items_df, cust_df, how='inner', on='id')
m.date_start = pd.to_datetime(m.date_start, dayfirst=True)
m.date_sent = pd.to_datetime(m.date_sent, dayfirst=True)
m.loc[ (m.date_start < m.date_sent) * ( m.date_sent < pd.to_datetime("12/08/2022", dayfirst=True))].reset_index()

#       id   item  date_sent date_start
#0  212175  PX002 2022-05-21 2022-05-20
#1  212175  PX003 2022-06-01 2022-05-20
#2  286170  PX002 2022-05-19 2022-05-18
#3  286170  PY005 2022-07-10 2022-05-18
#4  286170  PX003 2022-07-15 2022-05-18
#5  286170  NX002 2022-06-15 2022-05-18
```

Comment: This solution is really useful. Thanks

Comment: question , is 12/08/2022 supposed to be August 12 or December 8th ? Adjust dayfirst=True/False accordingly...

Comment: It's 12th August and yes i've adjusted the date accordingly. I changed it in the last line from "12/08/2022" to "2022/08/12". Cheers